# Throwing and catching exceptions correctly

Tags: java, exception

So I have this one question. Lets say we have classes: `Main`, `Info`, `Cats`, `Food`

Now, lets say that in main we create new object `Info`. In `Info` object we are saving list of `Cats` that have been created. `Cats` are being created and stored in `Info` class and `Food` is being created and stored in `Cats` class. Now lets say, that in `Main` class, I want to get specific `Food` object, which is stored in `Cats` class. So, in order to do so we do the following:

`Info.getFood(name)`. Then in `Info's` `getFood` method we say `Cats.getFood(name)`. Finally, in `Cats` class we have method `getFood`, in which we try to find Food object by its field "name". If we are unable to find such an element, we throw `NoSuchElement` exception rather than return an object. Here is my question:

If we throw exception in `Cats` class `getFood` method, should we catch that exception in `Main` class (where our interface is), in `Info` class (which is our system class) or in both of them?

Comment: Can you create [mock code](http://www.sscce.org/) instead of words?

Comment: Catch the exception in the context that knows what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, inside a method, if you can do something with the `Exception` being thrown (log an error, show an error message, make a different decision in your code, etc), then you should catch it. Otherwise, just throw it to the calling method.

As with many other coding practices, it all boils down to what you and your team agree on.

A concrete example which isn't related to your code, but which will show you how the decision process can be made. Assume the following code:

```
public MyConfiguration loadConfiguration () throws ConfigurationException {
    MyConfiguration config = null;

    try {
        readConfigurationFromFile ();

        // Parse configuration string

    } catch (IOException ioex) {
        throw new ConfigurationException (ioex);
    }

    return config;
}

private String readConfigurationFromFile () throws IOException {
    String configuration = "";

    // Read a file on disk, append data to the string.

    return configuration;
}
```

In `readConfigurationFromFile ()`, if an exception occurs while reading the file, you'll get an `IOException`. At this point in the code, there's no real action you can take, since this method only reads the configuration file, appends the data to a `String`, then returns it.

In `loadConfiguration ()`, you can surround the call to `readConfigurationFromFile ()` with a `try/catch`, and throw a more generic exception (`ConfigurationException`). Again, at this point, there's nothing you can do with the exception, except wrap it in a new exception which adds more context information to the original exception that was thrown.

Now assume that there's two flavors of your software: a GUI version, and a command-line version. If you are running the GUI flavor, then the method calling `loadConfiguration` could decide to show an error message to the user whenever a `ConfigurationException` is being thrown, so that the user knows that something happened. If you are running the command-line version, then maybe it would be more logical to add an entry to some error log with the exception that was caught.

Comment: But should you catch it in all of the methods, or just in the "main" one? A hierarchy of methods: getFood() -> getFood2() -> okGetFood()(we throw exception here). So where to catch it: in getFood, or getFood2, or both of them?

Comment: You can't catch it in "all" of them, unless your rethrow the exception after catching it.

Comment: @user3178137 The question you need to answer is "_Is there something I can do with this exception at this level?_". For instance, if you can't make any decision in `getFood2()`, but you can decide to display an error message in `getFood()`, then catch it in `getFood()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following site says "Most of the developers are embarrassed when they have to choose between the two options. This type of decision should not be taken at development time. If you are a development team, it should be discussed between all the developers in order to have a common exception handling policy."

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions

Comment: Since it is a personal object, I don't have to talk about this with a team. I am trying to find out which way is better.

Comment: I don't know whether one way is "better" than the other. It depends.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you want to do after throwing that exception.

Say for instance that if all you want is to return any food object from any cat (and as you said 'Info' stores lots of cats) then you might have a catch in Info where you catch the NoSuchElement exception and then create  some logic that moves onto the next Cat in Info to get its food! Finally if you exhaust all the 'Cats' in Info with no food found, you can throw another exception inside Info that you catch in Main that lets main know, "There's no food".

Again that's just an example. As people have said, it's not a "Always do this..." kind of answer. It depends greatly on what you *need* to do when handling that *exception*